# How to list all files within subdirectories without the path?

Tags: find, ls

I have 1000 directories and 5-15 sub directories within them containing mp3 files.
I want to make a list of all the songs without their paths.
Is it doable?

Or is there a way to obtain the word after the last "\" from the path so that we can retrieve the file-name from it? Some regular expressions or something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456120/how-to-get-file-only-file-name-with-linux-find

You'll want the `find` command, and something like this:

```
find ./ -type f -printf "%f\n"
```

If you need to filter by file type (for example, if you have other types of files in the folders, such as .jpg cover images, and just want MP3s listed), then tack on the `name` switch:

```
find ./ -type f -name "*.mp3" -printf "%f\n"
```