# How to obtain a list of all the files recursively without listing the directories to which the files belong and sort the list of files alphabetically?

Tags: files, find, ls, sort

I only managed to list the directories themselves with *ls -a* or the files sorted by directory with *ls -aR*

Comment: No closing privileges here, [but](https://askubuntu.com/questions/329789/how-to-list-all-files-within-subdirectories-without-the-path)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `find` command's `-printf` with the `%f` format specifier to get just the files' basenames. From `man find`:

> ```
>           %f     Print  the basename; the file's name with any leading di‐
>                  rectories removed (only the last element).   For  /,  the
>                  result is `/'.
> ```

So for example

```
find . -type f -printf '%f\n' | sort
```

or (to handle filenames that contain newlines)

```
find . -type f -printf '%f\0' | sort -z | xargs -r0 -n1
```

To omit files in `.` itself, add `-mindepth 2`. Note that `find` matches hidden files by default, if that is why you added the `-a` flag to your `ls` command.

---

Alternatively using `zsh`

```
print -rC1 -- **/*(.:t:on)
```

To include hidden files in this case, set the globdots option (`setopt globdots`), and to omit files at the `.` level change the glob to `*/**/*`.

Comment: OP asks for the files in the sub-directories, so maybe `find .` is not completely appropriate. Otoh, I'm very happy of learning about `--printf` and its format directives, I've missed them for decades!

Comment: @gboffi thanks I added a note about using `-mindepth` although the OP had accepted the answer without it

Comment: An alternative to `-mindepth 2` is `find */ -type f ...` .  That excludes dot-directories like `.local/` assuming normal glob settings.  `*/` will expand to only the directories in the current directory and is a generally handy idiom to keep in mind.